# Copying from from one struct to another

Tags: c

Been working on this for 3 days and no progress, I'm still new to C.

What I'm trying to do is after getting data and stored into the struct RiderInfo.

void ridertopsort() is sorting based on the time.

void gettop() is to read what the racelength is and then store the data into tb struct. For now I'm trying to just figure out how to store the name only.

the 2nd and 3rd else if statement are bit different because I tried both ways in trying to copy name from Riderinfo to tb.

I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong, I can run the code but it exits directly without giving me any results and I know the problem is within the gettop() function.

```
struct shorrt
{
    char topname[3][81];
    int topagegroups[3];
    int tophrs[3];
    int topmin[3];
    char botname[3][81];
    int botagegroups[3];
    int bothrs[3];
    int botmins[3];
};

struct medium
{
    char topname[3][81];
    int topagegroups[3];
    int tophrs[3];
    int topmin[3];
    char botname[3][81];
    int botagegroups[3];
    int bothrs[3];
    int botmins[3];
};

struct lonng
{
    char topname[3][81];
    int topagegroups[3];
    int tophrs[3];
    int topmin[3];
    char botname[3][81];
    int botagegroups[3];
    int bothrs[3];
    int botmins[3];
};

struct tb 
{
    struct shorrt sr;
    struct medium mr;
    struct lonng lr;
};
```

```
struct RiderInfo
{
    char name[81];
    int age;
    char raceLength;
    int startTime;
    int mountainTime;
    int finishTime;
    int withdrawn;
};
```

```
void ridertopsort(struct RiderInfo info[]) 
{
    int i, j;
    struct RiderInfo sorttemp;
    for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 5000; j++) {
            if ((info[j].finishTime - info[j].startTime) < (info[i].finishTime - info[i].startTime))
            {
                sorttemp = info[j];
                info[j] = info[i];
                info[i] = sorttemp;
            }
        }
    }

}

void gettop(struct RiderInfo info[], struct tb topbtm[]) 
{
    int a,i,j,k,m;
    m = 0;
    i = 0;
    a = type();
    while(m == 0)
    {
        if (a == 1 && (info[i].raceLength == 's') || (info[i].raceLength == 'S'))
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 81; k++)
                {
                    strcpy(info[i].name, topbtm->sr.topname);
                    if (j == 2)
                    {
                        m = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if (a == 2 && (info[i].raceLength == 'm') || (info[i].raceLength == 'M'))
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 81; k++)
                {
                    strcpy(info[i].name, topbtm->mr.topname);
                    if (j == 2)
                    {
                        m = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (a == 2 && (info[i].raceLength == 'l') || (info[i].raceLength == 'L'))
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 81; k++)
                {
                    strcpy(info[i].name[k], topbtm->lr.topname[j][k]);
                    if (j == 2)
                    {
                        m = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger? It will pinpoint the line and reason immediately.

Comment: *"trying to copy name from `Riderinfo` to `tb`"* -- You have your parameters in `strcpy(info[i].name, topbtm->sr.topname);` in the wrong order. The usage is `strcpy (destination, source);` [man 3 strcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using type names that look like typos of C keywords like `short` and `long` isn't a great plan. Try and give these names that make sense. First you'll need to resolve why you have three different `struct` definitions that apart from the name are completely identical. I have a feeling what you really want is to strip out all the `[3]` stuff from those and have a singular `struct` you can stamp out *N* times.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to achieve the same results

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the fields of the instances of your structure, or use `memcpy()`.  For example, when you write,

```
void ridertopsort(struct RiderInfo info[]) 
{
    struct RiderInfo sorttemp;
// ...
```

You either can copy each field, with something like

```
memcpy(&sorttemp.name, &info[j].name, sizeof(sorttemp.name));
sorttemp.age = info[j].age;
// ...
```

Or copy the entire structure, with

```
memcpy(&sorttemp, &info[j], sizeof(sorttemp));
```

Also consider whether you really want three identical `struct` declarations.  if you really, truly want to keep that, you probably want to code defensively, with a few lines such as,

```
static_assert( sizeof(sorttemp) == sizeof(info[0]), "" );
```

This will at least protect you from changing the size of one of your structures in a way that breaks existing code, although not from breaking layout compatibility while leaving the size the same.

Comment: Hmm... wouldn't `sorttemp.name` already be a pointer due to array/pointer conversion? [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In this context, no. The line you quote begins, “Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, ...” which is how I use it here. `sizeof(sorttemp.name)` is 81.

Comment: I think we are miscommunicating, my fault, I was talking about the other parameters, `memcpy(&sorttemp.name, &info[j].name, ....)` both are character arrays to begin with, where `strcpy (sorttemp.name, info[j].name)` would be fine. (using the *address of* operator there changes the type from `char*` to `char (*)[81]` -- which by `memcpy`'s use of `void*` is happily ignored -- but it would be technically incorrect)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You’re right. In this context, either way works. So would `&sorttemp.name[0]` and `&info[j].name[0]`. I included the `&` from force of habit.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The one time it makes a difference is if a structure contains a pointer. Then, as you know, `memcpy( dest.p, src.p, size_of_what_p_points_to )` makes a deep copy and `memcpy( &dest.p, &src.p, sizeof(dest_p) )` makes a shallow one. So in that context, the expressions are not equivalent.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And I’m not sure why copying an object of type `char[81]` would be considered technically incorrect. It works the same as any other object. :)

Comment: It relates to the *type* being copied and that affects pointer-arithmetic. In the case of an array, taking the address of an array  and accessing the array itself both resolve to the same address, but have different types.. "Technically incorrect" probably wasn't the correct choice, "Technically unclear" would have been better. `memcpy(&sorttemp.name + 1, &info[j].name + 1, ....)` and `memcpy(sorttemp.name + 1, info[j].name + 1, ....)` would provide radically different results.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, if we were working with an `array[M][N]`, we would need to be precise about whether we wanted to increment by one cell, one row or the one array. Here, I personally prefer to be consistent with my syntax.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that I had the strcpy in the opposite, also changed up the struct after reading your comments since i realized I had too many indexes and would just make things more complicated.  Rather than memcpy, I continued to use strcpy since I wouldnt know the exact size for the info index actually. I'm asked to be prepared to copy up to 5000 indexes

Comment: I was able to run my whole program after some changes. However, the output isnt what I want and I have no idea what its outputting, it not garbage its printing tureContext, I'll probably have to opening another question for this since its already different than what I wanted to ask, yet I don't know if my function is copying stuff correctly.